# How can I attach a Parent Issue Name to a Subtask Name in Jira?

Tags: jira, agile, scrum

in a Jira Issue, I have a "Definition of Done" Field where we have 5 default tasks to execute before we can mark an Issue as done. From those tasks, I'm able to create a Subtask. However, I would like the name of those Subtasks to be automatically named as "{Parent Issue Name} / {Task Name}".
For example, from an Issue called "Website Redesign Project", I create a Subtask for a task called "CSS Alignment Issue", and the name of the Issue should be "**Website Redesign Project/ CSS Alignment Issue**".

Would it be possible to do something like that?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with automation.

Here is the configuration of automation that should be implemented.

1. **Trigger :** "Issue created"
2. **Condition :** "Issue fields condition"

> **Field :** Issue Type
> Blockquote
>
> **Condition :** equals
> Blockquote
>
> **Value :** Sub-task

3. **Action :** "Edit issue". And put the code below in the **More options > Additional fields**

```
{"fields": {"summary": "{{issue.parent.summary}}/ {{issue.summary}}"}}
```

**For information :**
If you use Jira Cloud, you should have automation installed by default.
But if you use Jira Data Center, you should install the add-on from the [Atlassian mMrketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1215460/automation-for-jira?tab=overview&hosting=datacenter).